# Selenium - IEdriver - Unable to create a second instance on the VM

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

When running an automated test case on the local machine i am able to run as many IEdrivers, Chrome, Firefox as i want.

However when i run same automated test case on the VM i am only able to run single IE driver. (Firefox and Chrome can run up to 5 drivers)

Issue: When creating a new IEdriver on the VM the whole program just freezes and sits there for hours without killing the process.

Side Note: Firefox and Chrome drivers run the same test with no issues.

Upon starting the Selenium hub and the node IE driver defaults to only 1 available instance, but Chrome and Firefox default to 5 instances. I am thought overriding the maxInstances for IE and setting it to 2, but that doesn't help.

IECapabilities that i set are

1. `INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS`, true
2. `NATIVE_EVENTS`, false
3. `IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING`, true
4. `IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION`, true
5. `ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP`, true
6. `FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS`, true
7. `IE_SWITCHES`, "-private"

Selenium Hub command:

```
java -jar C:\pathToSeleniumServer.jar -role hub
```

Node command:

```
java -jar C:\pathToSeleniumServer.jar -role node \
  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register/ \
  -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=2 \
  -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2 \
  -browser browserName=iexplore,maxInstances=2 -maxSession 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found my mistake.

In the node command browserName=iexplore has to be  browserName="internet explorer"